# relationship of mysql in laravel 5.5

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to model with Laravel a database for purchases, in my mysql the relations are [[image: [like this]] (for each table in the mysql i have one model)

so I was modeling in Laravel, for the associative table "`fornecedor_item_detalhe`" I used relation "`belongstoMany`", it worked out using tinker.

Now comes the problem:

1. together with the detalhes("fornecedor_detalhe") and the "items" I would like to be able to access the other tables related to "`fornecedor_detalhe`" which are "`fornecedor`" and "`formpagto`"."Has Many Through" will work For this?
2. And also I would like to link this associative table "`fornecedor_detalhes-Item`" in relation n: m with another table to create another associative table "`fornecedor_detalhe_item_rci`".

I've created a model for the pivot table "`fornecedor_detalhe_item`", but I'm not exactly sure how to do that, as long pivot tables don't have a primary key, how can i reference to them in the other pivot table

I did not codify anything, I'm just trying to model the same thing in laravel.

If you have any suggestions about MER I also accept it.

Thank you

Comment: Bem-vindo! Albeit, the main language here is English and you're kindly requested to translate your question in order to get some answers. Also, please consider formatting it properly.

Comment: You can also look at [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) if you'd rather not use English.

Answer (score 0):

just use Eloquent: Relationships
look in this link [realtion types](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)

and you should have model for fornecedor and formpagto

by build relation in model hasMany or belongsTo as your database structure you can call the anywhere just by type relation name
for example

in User Model

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

when you call in blade $user->post  you get all posts related to this user and so on

Comment: so far i have one model for each table in the mysql, i'm asking if i can make a relationship "belongstomany" with a table and a pivot table (creating another pivot table)

Comment: you build each alone stand in model. and when you call the record call it like this   for example   $user = User::with([  'Relation1','Relation2','Relation3'    ])->get();